# Not able to merge the inside and outside border in table in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to merge the borders in the table in HTML, can anyone suggest?
I have even used the border-collapse attribute..

```
    <html>
     <head>  
      <style>
       table{cellspacing : "0";}
       th{border-collapse : collapse;}
       .g{ border-width : thick ; border-color:blue;}
       td {text-align : center; cellpadding :"10";
       border-collapse:collapse;}
       caption{text-align:center;}
      </style>
     </head>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: You should post your HTML, not an image of it.

Comment: Please use something like https://jsfiddle.net to create an example. Also you should better describe your problem (for me it is unclear what you want)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `border-collapse`property on the table, not on the td!

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <table id="table">

    </table>
```

try this one

CSS:

```
#table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```